# How to add a custom step on password reset b2c?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, reset-password

I want to add a new step on password reset that basically needs to display a user custom attribute like extension_question1, which was stored during sign-up, and another field to provide the answer. I also want to make an API call to validate the answer.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your reset password experience using Custom Policies.

Check out [Configure password change using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) for detailed tutorial about how to do this.

*You will have to add just another `ClaimProvider` for extra question you want to add.*

Comment: Thanks for replying! It is clear when you need to add a new "field" to the user, but not sure how to display the extension_question1 stored during sign-up. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Pls check out this: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-reset-with-phone-number - you can use question instead of phone number.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example!